# VBA to copy a specific value in a new spreadsheet if satisfies condition

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to this VBA for excel.
I'm trying to write some code that will check (for 2 specific columns: let' say C and I) until it comes to a specific text and copies the column next to that value (from the column before) in a  different spreadsheet.

For Example, check if in column **C** and column **I** the word "Yes" exist: 
[image: Example]

If so, paste the Value (in the corresponding value in the Column before) in this case.
the cell: (1,2): **2000** and cell (2,9): **98** in a new spreadsheet.

[image: Desidered output_example]

So far I've built this code (it only check the column **C)**

The **1st part** (only check if the value that I'm searching exists)

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' t
        On Error Resume Next
            i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Yes", .Range("C:C"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If i <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Yes found at " & .Cells(i, 3).Address(0, 0)
        Else
            MsgBox "Yes not found in Column"
        End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

But I'm stuck when I try to implement the **2nd part** (copy the value from the column beside and paste it on a different spreadsheet)

Comment: `Match` will only return one instance. Better to use the `Find` method and `Offset` to get the cell to the left.

Comment: If `i` is the row, you want, then `Cells(i, 4)` is the cell in column D.

Comment: You want to find the matches in the column C an I, no matter the row they are? And take that values (with the YES word, next the cell) to another sheet, in the column next to the cells with the YES word (in order, no matter the row, but in a ordered list in the new sheet, to the columns offset 2 columns left)? I'm right?

Comment: And what if there is more than one YES word in any of the columns C and I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `Find`, overkill I guess if you only have one Yes in each column.

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range, s As String

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C,I:I")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:="Yes", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        s = rFind.Address
        Do
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = rFind.Offset(, -1).Value 'copy value in col B/H
            Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
        Loop While rFind.Address <> s
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would a filter not work? maybe I'm over simplifying it...

Comment: @Zac -  I don't think it would because the "Yes"es could be on different rows. Could do two filters I suppose.

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about as OP hasn't specifically mentioned that it could be any column or the 2 static columns. If it is just 2 columns, we could do the filter. But if we don't know which columns, `Find` is the way to go

Comment: I just prefer Find to AutoFilter. Still think you'd need 2 filters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim i As Long: i = 1000000
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Range
    Dim resultC As Range
    Dim resultI As Range
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet: Set Sht1 = Sheets("Sheets1")
    Dim Sht2 As Worksheet: Set Sht2 = Sheets("Sheets2")

    With Sht1
        For Each k In .Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(i, Range("C1").Column)) 'for each cells in the column C (Range("C1:C1000000")
            If k.Value = "YES" Then
                Set resultC = k 'store the findind into the var and
                Exit For 'exit the loop
            End If
        Next k

        For Each k In .Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(i, Range("I1").Column)) 'for each cells in the column I (Range("I1:I1000000")
            If k.Value = "YES" Then
                Set resultI = k
                Exit For
            End If
        Next k
    End With

    With Sht2
        j = .Range(Cells(1000000, 1), Cells(1000000, 1)).End.Row + 1 'find the last cell in the new list with the results
        .Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 1)).Value = resultC.Offset(0, -1).Value
        .Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j, 2)).Value = resultI.Offset(0, -1).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Don't know what you want to do with the values in the columns A and G (in the first picture). But please let me know if you have any issue.